# A confusing Typeerror appears at the anaconda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda

When I finished installing `minicoda` and opened the prompt to use `CONDA list` or other commands, I got a confusing `Typeerror`
such as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\huangwei\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 819, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\huangwei\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 74, in _main
    context.__init__(argparse_args=args)
  File "C:\Users\huangwei\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 237, in __init__
    argparse_args=argparse_args)
  File "C:\Users\huangwei\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 722, in __init__
    self._set_search_path(search_path)
  File "C:\Users\huangwei\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 728, in _set_search_path
    self._set_raw_data(load_file_configs(search_path))
  File "C:\Users\huangwei\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 369, in load_file_configs
    raw_data = odict(kv for kv in chain.from_iterable(load_paths))
  File "C:\Users\huangwei\Miniconda2\lib\collections.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.__update(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\huangwei\Miniconda2\lib\_abcoll.py", line 571, in update
    for key, value in other:
  File "C:\Users\huangwei\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 369, in <genexpr>
    raw_data = odict(kv for kv in chain.from_iterable(load_paths))
  File "C:\Users\huangwei\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 344, in _file_yaml_loader
    yield fullpath, YamlRawParameter.make_raw_parameters_from_file(fullpath)
  File "C:\Users\huangwei\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 336, in make_raw_parameters_from_file
    return cls.make_raw_parameters(filepath, ruamel_yaml) or EMPTY_MAP
  File "C:\Users\huangwei\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 325, in make_raw_parameters
    for key in from_map)
  File "C:\Users\huangwei\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 325, in <genexpr>
    for key in from_map)
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

the env is below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOdqY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxlDg.png)

Is there any good solution？

Thank you!

Comment: Did you already have Anaconda but then installed Miniconda on top of it? And why Miniconda2?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I search this problem in github and then got this answer https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7105

Comment: Sounds good! If the `conda update anaconda-navigator` worked for you, be sure to write it up as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As Merv says, if you haven't installed Minionda/Anaconda before, you can try `conda update anaconda-navigator` to fix this problem

but if you used to install Minionda/Anaconda and you didn't uninstall it cleanly, then you can fix this problem refer [this issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7105)